# Function “is not a function”

Tags: javascript

It looks like "save_masmoh_user is not a function" is a very common problem with JavaScript, yet after looking through quite a few threads I still cannot understand what is causing it in my case.

I have a custom object, defined as:

```
function save_masmoh_user() {
    var save_masmoh = $("#save_masmoh").serialize();
    var ft_user_id = $('#ft_user_id').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>myaccount/saveMasmohToUser/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            save_masmoh: save_masmoh,
            ft_user_id: ft_user_id
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.msg == "save") {

                alert("Done");

            } else {

                alert("Error");

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `It looks like "save_masmoh_user is not a function" is a very common problem with JavaScript`, I would have to say "no". Where does your error occur?

Comment: when click to `<input type="button" onclick="save_masmoh_user();" id="save_masmoh_user" value="Save">`

Comment: Where is the js file being included? Or is it a script tag in your layout?

Comment: Do you have `save_masmoh_user` wrapped in a function - maybe a document load handler?

Comment: i include this function in the same page that have html but not work

Comment: You mean like this: `<script>function save_masmoh_user() {…}</script>`?

Comment: If it is exactly that, then more context is needed.  Can you provide a fiddle that reproduces the problem?  As stated above it works for me: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/DbNNE/) with no unload wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

It means that your function is not in the scope that you are calling it in. I am guessing you are calling it as a global and you have it defined in an onready block. Hard to tell with the lack of code.

You should probably be using unobtrusive code so call it with

```
$("#yourId").on("click", save_masmoh_user);
```